# How do I add an in-line pause in a For loop?

Tags: windows, for-loop, inline, command-prompt

I am trying to pause the loop for a user-input [Eg. `Press any key`] after each item in the loop.

`for %i in (server1,server2) do (ping %i)| pause`   doesn't work.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I have tried the `choice` and `pause` the `more` commands. Can't get it to work.

Comment: Maybe move pause inside parenthesis?

Comment: @Dialecticus In that case it pauses before pinging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in the comment was right.

```
for %i in (server1,server2) do (ping %i & pause)
```